# How to use python code combines two excel tables to form two tables of one excel table

Tags: python

look like combines A.xlsx and B.xlsx to a new excel inclouding two sheets :
sheet1 is A.xlsx and sheet2 is B.xlsx

I originally split an excel table containing two sheets according to the same column, hoping that each different element after splitting can be divided into an excel table containing two sheets ,
But after splitting, the two sheets are also divided into two excel sheets, so now I hope to merge the two excel sheets into two sheets of one excel sheet

Below is my codename

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel("2023.2.7RFID125款.xlsx",converters={"BARCODE":str,"SKU":str},sheet_name=0)
nodeDataList = list(df1.groupby(['STYLE']))
for nodeData in nodeDataList:
    nodeData[1].to_excel('包装要求'+ str(nodeData[0])+ '.xlsx', sheet_name='包装要求', index=False)# index=False输出不显示索引值
    
df2 = pd.read_excel("2023.2.7RFID125款.xlsx",converters={"BARCODE":str,"SKU":str},sheet_name=1)
nodeDataList = list(df2.groupby(['STYLE']))
for nodeData in nodeDataList:
    nodeData[1].to_excel('数据' + str(nodeData[0])+ '.xlsx',sheet_name='数据', index=False)
```

Comment: Could you explain what you've tried before, and what worked and didn't work? It's hard to solve your issue when we don't know what you're working with (libraries, databases, etc.). A [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

a good soln is given here , do check it out . basically they have done it using openpyxl which involves finding absolute path of our sheets , then creating sheets in the new workbook and then copying that data to our sheets.
[Combining multiple Excel sheets into one in Python](https://www.pylenin.com/blogs/combining-workbooks-to-sheets/)

Comment: thx bro ，but  I have a lot of excel files and I want it to be done in one go，Actually merging can be done on excel, but I still want to do it in one step

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).